# Hardcode date in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Have a question on Informatica powercenter. We have a target column END_DATE in oracle as date which is populated from a different column. I put an expression transformation and used an IF condition.

IIF(Status='Expired',Currentdate,'12/31/9999')

Basically, if status column has a value 'Expired' it will update END_DATE column as current date ELSE it will put an infinite date such as '12/31/9999'.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually it was giving an syntax error. No its fixed. I put the SYSDATE and then TO_DATE(12/31/9999,mm/dd/yyyy) . It worked. Thanks.

Comment: glad that you were able to work it out. Now either `delete` the question or put the solution as answer and accept it, so the question could be closed. Thanks.